# How to add custom key in UIToolBar keyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitoolbar

I would like to add custom key (red dott on image) for decimal numbers, how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I only have to select Keyboard: "Decimal pad" like on screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem you can just change your keyboard type to UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation:

```
amountTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
```

If you use this, then there is no need to add tool bar also... You need to just add "RETURNKEYTYPE" of UIKeyBoard as UIReturnKeyDone

```
amountTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

For Example:

```
amountTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 4, 190, 26)];
amountTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
amountTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
amountTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
amountTextField.delegate = self;
```

Comment: This is not solution because with that I get all buttons like: -,:, anad et. Only what I need is to add one extra button to my number keypad which has only numbers.

Comment: Sorry, but you di not solve a qustion which is; "How to add custom key in UIToolBar keyboard?" I want be able to add any custom button to that empty space slot.